# Why do my image views placed inside a scroll view have distorted heights?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have an array of `UIImageViews` with each a different image and a function that places them inside a `UIScrollView` so they can be automatically scrolled like a slideshow. My scroll view has a height of 150 pixels and the images are 400x150 PDF's.

For some odd reason on the iPhone 5 simulator my images are vertically distorted, while they appear completely normal on the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus counterparts. Would anyone have any insight as to why this is happening?

Here is my code:

```
var pageViews: [UIImageView] = []
    @IBOutlet weak var carousel: UIScrollView!

    func showPage() {
        //Sets up the image views with their images inside the scroll view
        for (index, page) in enumerate(pageViews) {
            var frame = carousel.frame
            page.frame = CGRectMake(frame.size.width * CGFloat(index), 0, carousel.frame.width, page.image!.size.height)
            page.frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
            page.contentMode = .ScaleToFill
            carousel.addSubview(page)
        }
    }
```

The above function is being called in viewDidAppear(). I've tried calling it in viewDidLoad() and viewDidLayoutSubviews() but there was no difference. I've also tried changing the `UIViewContentMode` to other options like `.ScaleAspectFit` which fixed the height distortion but the images no longer filled their image views which made everything look weird. I've tried changing image sizes but that had no effect. And lastly I've tried `page.sizeToFit()` which messed up everything badly. I'm kind of lost right now.. Help?

Comment: Are you sure they aren't distorted on the 6 and 6+ too? Those phones have widths much closer to 400 than the 5, so it might just be harder to tell.  If you set your image view to `.ScaleToFill` it will distort the images if their aspect ratio is not the same as the aspect ratio of the image view.  You can set it to `ScaleAspectFill` and it will keep the aspect ratio and fill up the entire image view.  This will cause either some of the top/bottom or left/right of the image to be cut off though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the image view `clipToBounds` to `true` and the `UIViewContentMode` as `.Center` fixed the problem! This is probably a temporary solution but works well for now. Thanks for the help